# Passing data between two window's in one xib file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

New to Objective C and cocoa developing, busy playing with some code writing app to just practice a bit, and I have a bit of a problem.

Got a xib with a window and a HUB panel in it. The HUB panel is hidden, on the window there's a button, which diplay's the HUB with

```
[self.myHUBWindow orderFront.sender];
```

works perfectly, then on the hub I got a text field and a button that close the HUB, close button, works 100% as well :

```
[self.myHUBWindow close];
```

What I want to do is, when I click the button on the main window, it should insert some text into the
text field on the HUB window. I have this :

```
 [self.hubOutputTextField insertText:@"hello world"];
```

Nothing seems to happen :-/ Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My main window button IBAction :

```
- (IBAction)buildScannerButton:(id)sender {
    [self.myHUBWindow orderFront:sender];
    [self.hubOutputTextField insertText:@"hellow world"];
}
```

and my @property for the text field

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *hubOutputTextField;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[self.hubOutputTextField setStringValue:@"hello world"];
```

Comment: Thanks that works, however it seems the text in the TextField get's over written each time with setStringValue, with insertText I can keep on appending strings to the text field. Works to a text field on my main window, but for some reason does not work to one on the HUB window :-/

Comment: if you want to append use, an nsmutableString, append it, then setStringValue:mutableString :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort of managed to get it working

```
[self.hubOutputTextField setStringValue:@"First line\n"];
self.hubOutputTextField.stringValue = [self.buildOutputTextField.stringValue stringByAppendingString:@"secoand line"];
```

Which is fine, was just hoping for a cleaner way to do it. I can imagine if you have loads of strings to add this can get ugly quickly, suppose just make a method to do it. Anyone know of a better way?

Comment: If you want to display multiple lines, you should use a text view rather than a text field. Conveniently, NSTextViews respond to `insertText:` just fine (although what you really should do is get the text view's `textStorage`, get the mutable `string` from that, and send that string `appendString:` messages).