# Pass Data between xib files without storyboard in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xib

I am new to swift (and new to StackOverflow) and learning to use nib files now as I did quite a bit of learning with storyboard already. 
In storyboard we can instantiate segues and unwindSegues to fetch data from one VC to another. How can I do the same WITHOUT using storyboard?

I currently have a scrollview(*MainViewController.xib*) that loads a tableview(*ContactView.xib*) on it. I have an add button overlaying the tableview which is currently unresponsive.
I want to be able to load another view (*AddContact.xib*) when I click on the add button to add a new data to my tableview and then unwind to reflect the new data in the table, but WITHOUT using storyboard.

I can provide my code if needed, but am only looking for someone to point me in the correct direction. I know this can be achieved using Navigation Controllers but I can't seem to find a fitting tutorial for it (most are old and use Obj-C. I am unfamiliar with Obj-C).

I even looked at some similar questions like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881524/pass-data-from-tableviewcontroller-to-xib-file-without-segues-swift-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133128/passing-data-between-two-windows-in-one-xib-file)
but they failed to answer my question.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

My AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var mainVC: MainViewController? = nil


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    mainVC = MainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
    let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
    window!.rootViewController = mainVC
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true

}
```

MainViewController.swift:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let contactView: ContactView = ContactView(nibName: "ContactView", bundle: nil)
    let dialerView: DialerView = DialerView(nibName: "DialerView", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(dialerView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(dialerView.view)
    dialerView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(contactView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(contactView.view)
    contactView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    var contactViewFrame : CGRect = contactView.view.frame
    contactViewFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    contactView.view.frame = contactViewFrame

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.height)
}
}
```

My ContactView.xib:

```
class ContactView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var names = ["Rohan", "Rahul", "Sneh", "Paa", "Maa", "Vatsal", "Manmohan"]
var numbers = ["9830000001", "9830000002", "9830000003", "9830000004", "9830000005", "9830000006", "9830000007"]
let navVC: UINavigationController? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(60)
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Contact")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Contact", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.numLabel.text = numbers[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

// Make delete-able in scroll view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        names.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        numbers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

My *AddContact.xib* only has the outlets defined.

**Edit:** I found a solution thanks to the commenters.
To Anyone wondering how I did it, I'll post the steps below:

Step 1: Create a protocol (I did so in my *MainViewController.xib*)

```
protocol NewContactDelegate {
    func add_Contact (name: String, num: String)
}
```

Step 2: Instantiate a delegate for it in the senderVC. *AddContact.xib* was the senderVC for me

```
class AddContact: UIViewController {

var delegate: NewContactDelegate? = nil
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func saveContact(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if delegate != nil {
        if let name = nameField?.text, let num = numField?.text {
            delegate?.add_Contact(name: name, num: num)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: Make ReceivingVC conform to the delegate and accept data.

```
class ContactView: ....., NewContactDelegate {

func add_Contact(name: String, num: String) {
    names.append(name)
    numbers.append(num)
    addressBook.reloadData() // This is my TableView outlet
}
}
```

**

> NOTE: Remember to assert the delegate to a non-nil value in the *RecievingVC* to make sure `@IBAction` in *SenderVC* works as expected.

**

Comment: Please provide code, BTW you can also just embed your controller in Navigation and than just use push and pop for this.

Comment: you need to create a `protocol` assign the protocol to `MainViewController ` and create a delegate of that protocol on `AddContact `

Comment: @Shabirjan Hi i have provided the code now. I have not added any code for the navigations yet because i'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @rudydydy I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand. Do you mean, a protocol for a Navigation Controller?

Comment: `protocol`s are used to share data between different viewControllers. Look up `ios Stanford lectures` on `youtube`. You'll find detailed lectures to get you started with iOS

Comment: Usa Protocols to achieve this.

Comment: @Malik I see. Ok I am going take a look at protocols. :)

Comment: @Shabirjan Thanks a lot. I figured it out! Protocols were the way to go indeed! :D

Comment: Welcome protocols are awesome in Swift.

Comment: @Shabirjan yes. so easy to use :D